# Maven build failed for struts2 showcase

Tags: java, maven, struts2, jboss, wildfly-8

I read about the struts2-showcase and found the maven repository at https://mvnrepository.com

Maven repository I am using is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-showcase/2.3.16.3

I am trying to create one project using the given `pom.xml` given in the maven repo. But whenever I run `mvn install`, its giving build failure. Firstly I was doing this by creating one project using

> mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=struts
> -DartifactId=struts2-showcase -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

command in console. Then I opened the pom.xml and added the dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-showcase</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.16.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I run the command

> mvn install

I got error in test and at last Build failure.

But Later I deleted all and created a directory manually and inside that I created one `pom.xml` and pasted all the contents got from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-showcase/2.3.16.3/pom

Then all worked perfectly but nothing to compile and nothing to test and got build successful. But when I deployed it got the error and build failed.

I know I am doing something terribly wrong. Someone please show me the way to make it work.
As application server I used JBoss (wildfly).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download or checkout from the [source repository](http://struts.apache.org/builds.html) a source distribution. Once done, navigate to the folder (`${base_dir}\src\apps\showcase\`)  with `pom.xml` and run `mvn`. It will `install` the project from `pom.xml`. If you need additional info you can check docs [Building with Maven](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html).

Comment: I tried this but after running mvn command its showing build success but when I put the struts2-showcase.war file, generated in the target, I got the error in jboss server and the struts2-showcase.war.failed is generated.

Comment: If you have another question, post it by the button [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).