# Struts 2 distribution - two "strange" file names

Tags: struts2, installation

I have just downloaded a Full Distribution of [Struts 2.3.24](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts2324).

When unzipping it I had a problem with the following two **file names**:

- `struts-2.3.24\docs\docs\bookmark-portlet.zip?version=1&modificationDate=1199675399000&api=v2`
- `struts-2.3.24\docs\docs\example.gif?api=v2`

For now I just ignored them.

My question is:

Is it a bug in a distribution (unresolved targets) or does Struts require a more sophisticated archive utility that actually can handle something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably archived a wrong name and a bug in distribution. I've seen such files in some zipped files or you have wrong zip utility. In either way you can test the archive for errors with `-t` option. If Struts required more sophisticated utility you were unable extract files from it.

Comment: I tested the archive with `7-Zip` and it showed no problems.  I then unzipped it without errors and it did actually create files with these *weird* names. Seems more and more like a bug in a release builder.

Comment: You can build it yourself, Struts team provides you the access to the source repository. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24595066/573032) answer. Also you can check the checksum of the files to make sure it's an original.